# How can I create a software patcher for OS X?

Tags: objective-c, osx, software-updates, cocoa, software-patches

I'm building some software for OS X that isn't distributed through the Mac App Store. My software allows users to download different modules uploaded by various people too.

How can I create a software patcher to patch my software, as well as update modules that users might be uploading when necessary? I've looked a bit into diff and patch, which come with OS X but they seem to be largely for plaintext.

Any ideas? I've been googling but I'm a bit stumped which is surprising since software patching seems to be in most applications.

Comment: sam way you do in any language on any platform...

Comment: Yes Rig, I'm not sure how that's done exactly which is why I asked ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) utility should come with OSX.  If that can't work for you, there are other [binary diff tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool-for-very-large-files).

However, with the advent of high bandwidth connections, the practice of distributing binary patches is becoming much less common.  You can just as easily distribute a complete updated version of your program if need be..

FURTHER: A [good] module system should not require you to patch your program whenever someone wants to download and install another user's module.  I suggest a system where this is not the case.  For example, have your program scan a plugins directory and load any valid plugin files found.

Comment: This is good advice, but be aware of the security risks involved in running third party plugins.

Comment: @Caleb you mean "*also* be aware of the security..."?  From what I understand the OP is going to use 3rd party code either way.  I don't think I suggested a less secure method.  In either case, ideally you would have a plugin submission process if security is of the utmost concern.

Comment: Right -- anytime you create a system that lets third party plugins run in your app, you open up a security hole. I certainly didn't mean that your suggestion was any less secure except insomuch as it stands a better chance of actually working than the OP's plan.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't update the whole application every time someone's module needs updating- but I was thinking that patching their software probably follows a pretty similar path as patching our own. Thanks for pointing me towards BSDiff, I'll check it out.